is there a term which recognizes the angst we experience between the values of knowing what happens next or enjoying the suspense in discovery?
Pleasurable suspense is defined as, the pleasurable emotion of anticipation and excitement regarding the outcome or climax of a book, film etc., but it also includes preferring to experiencing life not knowing what happens next.  It’s part of ignorance is bliss, especially when knowing is not only boring, it implies more responsibility.
Challenges are similar, and we lose the natural enjoyment-chemistry they offer if we already know the outcomes.  However, the more we know what happens next, the more confident we are in doing what’s required to get more of what we want, and the more responsible we can be by preparing ahead of time.
Is there a word which recognizes the angst we feel as we struggle between the two options, of knowing if we can, or not knowing because it’s either: 1) more fun/suspenseful; 2) more challenging; and/or 3) it causes us to be more responsible?
For example, she was unable to make a choice because of the {word} she felt, or he tends to avoid knowing what’s ahead whenever he feels {word}.
I can think of words like torn between and wrestling with, but they are more about the struggle and not what the substance of the struggle is.

You talk about "pleasurable suspense" as an emotion, which is conceivable; it is something that one is subjected to (since an experience), but then you add that a preference for experiencing life in a certain way (not knowing what happens next) is part of this experience; however, a preference is a predisposition, not something you are subjected to. What do you mean by "includes"? Perhaps you meant to say that this experience of pleasurable suspense goes along with the given preference? Is there no relation between those two that you might render more explicit?

@LPH the first time we experience the pleasure of suspense, we learn that's an option, to choose/prefer it, as opposed to learning 'how to' anticipate-and-prepare instead (know).  All of that happens unconsciously first, but the angst I'm referring to is consciously experienced, which most people are not able to describe very well...and the word I'm searching for with it's attached meaning could help.

There might be, if you could explain what difference there is between the values of knowing what happens next or enjoying the suspense or discovery?

@RobbieGoodwin knowing what happens next enables us to specifically prepare for it, from making something good even better, to preventing something bad altogether.  The value of suspense is excitement and the potential for awe.  Does that help?

That certainly doesn't hurt, and to me, for one, it makes it more likely that no; there is no such term.
Can you say what text, in what original language, gave rise to the Question?

@RobbieGoodwin I'm writing about wisdom in English, and wrestling with this topic:  is it wiser to learn what is more likely to happen next and prepare for it, or live more spontaneously and learn from each experience. And as I conduct my research, I'm noticing how much stress exists in the middle when it is truly better to prepare, and it's [that feeling] I believe informs and motivates us to prepare instead of living more spontaneously. And when we do not feel that angst, it is wiser to live more spontaneously...until experiences teaches us otherwise.

That still doesn't hurt, and to me it makes even more likely there is no such term.
To me, it also makes it virtually certain the Question belongs not to EL&U but to a thread dedicated to Philosophy.

@RobbieGoodwin my question is not about the philosophy, it's about a word that recognizes the feeling we experience when we struggle between doing what's required to be more prepared, or enjoying the thrill of jumping (or merely existing) into the unknown.

I don't know of a word that captures this specific notion, but there are certainly options that capture the idea of feeling contradicting feels about something, like ambivalent.

@NuclearHoagie that is a great word!  I just studied it's morphology: ambi=both sides and  valentia=strength.  And when we place that word in front of the two or more options it works!  My ambivalence toward knowing or discovering is holding me back.   Thanks.

Gosh, Christopher… if only the original Question had hinted at anything like that!
Another time, could you either state your first languages, or use somewhere such as English Language Learners, rather than ELU?
